# Track encrypted IP addresses in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, encryption, google-analytics, ip-address

I understand that Google will not share IP addresses of users it tracks, and that it's against their TOS for you to store any personally identifiable information. However, would it be permissible for you to store an encrypted version of a user's IP address as a custom variable in Google Analytics?

If so, what's a recommended way to encrypt an IP address so it's easily reversible? Ideally reversible in Excel.

Comment: any encryption is easily reversible given the appropriate encryption method and key... that's the point of encryption.  Hard for people that don't have your "key", easy for you because you have the key.  Also, not a lawyer so can't really give legal advice on what is or isn't against a TOS.

Comment: You're probably better off starting your own mini analytics for ips and pulling the data from your analytics account via their API, then connecting the two data sets there in this case :-)